# Excel VBA - Find file with Dir based on keyword or ask user to path it

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA, I'm pulling a few macros together. It need to find a file based on a given Path (stored in `C2`) and a Keyword (stored in `D2`) and than print the complete path into `E2` , if this file is not found, prompt a dialog so the user can find it (in case a spell mistake is made for example).

What I have so far:

```
 Public Sub Pather()

    'Find path to File1 based on KeyWord1
    Dim File1 As Variant, KeyWord1 As String, Path1 As String
    KeyWord1 = Sheet5.Range("d2").Text
    Path1 = Sheet5.Range("c2").Text
   File1 = Dir(MainPath & Path1)
   While (File1 <> "")
      'insert keyword below

      If Sheet5.Range("E2") = "" Then
      'Print File1 path into E2
        Sheet5.Range("E2") = Path1 & File1
      ' Display Error message for test reason
      ' (change to Dialog Script so user can find File1 )
      Else:
         MsgBox "File not found."
         '*** add FileDialog here ***
         Exit Sub
      End If
     File1 = Dir
  Wend

    End Sub
```

Works if I leave `Else` out... but when I include `Else`, if the file exists, it return both the File path into `E2` and display the alert. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I want it to display the alert and than run the following script:

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim FileName As String
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
'the number of the button chosen
Dim FileChosen As Integer
FileChosen = fd.Show
fd.Title = "Choose workbook"
fd.InitialFileName = "C:\test"
fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
'show Excel workbooks and macro workbooks
fd.Filters.Clear
fd.Filters.Add "Excel workbooks", "*.xlsx"
fd.Filters.Add "Excel macros", "*.xlsm"
fd.FilterIndex = 1
fd.ButtonName = "Choose this file"
If FileChosen <> -1 Then
'didn't choose anything (clicked on CANCEL)
MsgBox "No file choosen. File wont be saved as .PDF"
Else
'get file, and open it (NAME property
'includes path, which we need)
FileName = fd.SelectedItems(1)
Workbooks.Open (FileName)
End If
```

Is it possible to embed this 2nd script into the 1st?

Thanks soooo much

Comment: To fix your first issue, use "Else" instead of "Else:"

Comment: @GordonK thanks, but it still doing both results, looks like its running in a loop or something

Answer (score 0):

What is your input for Path1 in cell C2?
If it's a folder then the While loop goes on while there are any files to go through. That's why you get multiple outputs (i.e. return of both possible outcomes).

Also what is the purpose of KeyWord1? Is it supposed to be a wildcard, extension, or file name?

EDIT:

for listing all files that match the wildcard use:

```
   Public Sub Pather()

    'Find path to File1 based on KeyWord1
    Dim File1 As Variant, KeyWord1 As String, Path1 As String
    KeyWord1 = Sheet5.Range("d2").Text
    Path1 = Sheet5.Range("c2").Text
   File1 = Dir(MainPath & Path1)
   Dim i As Integer
   i = 1
   While (File1 <> "")
      'insert keyword below
    Debug.Print File1
      If Cells(i, 5) = "" Then

        If InStr(File1, KeyWord1) > 0 Then
            'Print File1 path into E2
              Cells(i, 5) = Path1 & File1
            ' Display Error message for test reason
            ' (change to Dialog Script so user can find File1 )
            i = i + 1
            'Exit Sub
        End If
      Else
         Debug.Print "File not found"
         MsgBox "File not found."
         '*** add FileDialog here ***
         Exit Sub
      End If
     File1 = Dir
    Wend

    End Sub
```

If you want to list only first that matches the wildcard, remove the ' symbol from: 'Exit Sub (so it exits after the first match is found).

Comment: Yes, you were spot on, Path1 in cell C2 is C:\test\ and KeyWord1 is a word that I want the macro to find inside Path1 folder eg.: "Contract"
I thought to do this way so it will be easier to other users to modify the path and keyword for different uses...
How do I fix it? Any idea on how to get the same result in a more efficient way?

Comment: See the code in my post. I forgot to add the code as posted will search for KeyWord1 inside the File1 path and lists ALL matching files in column E , that's the Cells(i, 5). If you rerun it you should first delete content in column E. Adjust to your needs.

Comment: how can I do  'Cells(i, 5) = Path1 & File1' always print in Sheet3 I tried Sheet3.Cells(i, 5) = Path1 & File1 but got error

Comment: What kind of error? 
Try Sheet3.Cells(i, 5).value = ... maybe it helps